# PSD to SharePoint Templates

Tags: templates, sharepoint, xhtml, photoshop

I require some help with “customized SharePoint templates”. Is there a way to convert a .PSD to a SharePoint template? I have experience with converting .PSD to Wordpress themes, but can you do the same in SharePoint? Any good tutorials online?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a SharePoint template by customizing a **MasterPage**

To get started create a minimal MasterPage: [How to: Create a Minimal Master Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa660698%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Slice your PSD to HTML using the minimal MasterPage.

SharePoint `MasterPages` have multiple `PlaceHolder` controls for `PageLayouts` to insert content in specific parts of the `MasterPage`.

The key `PlaceHolder` for page specific content is `PlaceHolderMain`

Other placeholders that you may utilize in `PageLayouts` include:

- `PlaceHolderPageTitle` for the page title (text within `<head><title>[Page Title]</title>...</head>`)
- `PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead` for additional CSS/JavaScript includes

MasterPage:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" />
```

PageLayout:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    ... <!-- page specific content, usually involving a WebPartManager -->
</asp:Content>
```

Additional Reading:

- [Heather's Base Master Page File for SharePoint 2007](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2007/01/26/6153.aspx)
- [How to Create a SharePoint Server 2007 Custom Master Page and Page Layouts for a Web Content Management Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727372%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Real World Branding with SharePoint Server 2007 Publishing Sites (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354191.aspx)
- [Real World Branding with SharePoint Server 2007 Publishing Sites (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354190.aspx)

Comment: This may be handy as it has Photoshop screenshots as part of the tutorial [Real World Branding with SharePoint Server 2007 Publishing Sites (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354191.aspx)